# How to get stack trace for all warnings?

Tags: perl, warnings, stack-trace

Is it possible to get a stack trace printed for all warnings?

I can get it for all errors with: `perl -MCarp::Always my_script.pl`

But how can I get it for warnings?

Answer (score 4):

`perl -d:Confess script.pl`

from http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/Devel-Confess-0.006001/lib/Devel/Confess.pm